# XML Message from UNIX Pipe via Stream Component

Tags: stream, apache-camel

I have a process that outputs multiple XML documents to a UNIX named pipe in a continuous stream. I'd like to be able to take that named pipe input and create multiple XML messages in the "from" portion of a camel route.

The Stream component seemed to be the natural choice to consume the named pipe input, but each line of the XML text is converted into a message instead of the whole XML document being the message.

I know I'm missing something fundamental here, but my google-foo has come up empty...

Any pointers on how to accomplish this greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

So more RTFM'ing and I have a solution.

```
from("file:/tmp?fileName=tshark-pipe&noop=true")
    .split().tokenizeXML("packet").streaming()
    .log("body: ${body}");
```

I found the above solution in the Camel "Splitter" EIP documentation page.